# Question about testing significance

Tags: statistical-significance

If I am comparing where there are any significant differences in the number of damaged apples between apple types, what kind of statistical test should I use?

There are 5 types of apples with different sample sizes.

| Apple Type | Number of observed apples | Number of damaged apples |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Granny Smith | 2500 | 233 |
| Fuji | 2000 | 135 |
| Golden Delicious | 1500 | 68 |
| Honey Crisp | 1200 | 48 |
| Gala | 950 | 14 |

*The data in the table has not been actually researched. I was created just for an example.

I would really appreciate it if somebody could tell me what kind of test I should use and why.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well your question, you would like to test whether the number of damaged apples is dependent on the apple type or if all apple types produce the same amount of damaged apples. If we suppose that the number of damaged apples is **independent of the apple type** and that you have the **same amount** of apples of each type, then, each damaged apple has a chance of $1/( number \ of \ apple \ type ) = \frac{1}{5}$ to be in one of the category Granny Smith, Fuji, Golden Delicious, Honey Crisp and Gala. Let us note this category $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$ and $5$ for respectively Granny Smith, Fuji, Golden Delicious, Honey Crisp and Gala for simplicity. From here, you can state the null hypothesis for your problem:

- $H_0$ : for a damaged apple you have a probability of $\frac{1}{5}$ that the apple belongs to the $i$-th apple type,

while your alternative hypothesis is

- $H_1$ : for a damaged apple you have a probability different  of $\frac{1}{5}$ that the apple belongs to the $i$-th apple type.

Now you have to compute the **empirical** probability that a damaged apple is part of one of the apple type and you calculate it from your data. Because we supposed at the beginning that we have at disposal the same amount of apple of each type, we can do a 'scaling' operation of your data to to simulate it as follows:

- Number of damaged apple of category 1: 233/2500*1000 = 93.2,
- Number of damaged apple of category 2: 135/2000*1000 = 67.5,
- Number of damaged apple of category 3: 68/1500*1000 =  45.3,
- Number of damaged apple of category 4: 48/1200*1000 =  40.0,
- Number of damaged apple of category 5: 14/950*1000 =   14.7.

So, in this case, the total number of damaged apples is $93.2+67.5+45.3+40+14.7 = 260.7$. Then we have as empirical probability for each apple types:

- $\hat{p}_1 = 93.2/260.7 = 0.358$ for type 1,
- $\hat{p}_2 = 67.5/260.7 = 0.259$ for type 2,
- $\hat{p}_3 = 45.3/260.7 = 0.174$ for type 3,
- $\hat{p}_4 = 40.0/260.7 = 0.153$ for type 4,
- $\hat{p}_5 = 14.7/260.7 = 0.056$ for type 5,

and we will now conduct a chi squared test of adequation to discover whether the probabilities $\hat{p}_1,\hat{p}_2,\hat{p}_3,\hat{p}_4$ and $\hat{p}_5$ differ from the supposed probabilities $p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4$ and $p_5$ all equal to $\frac{1}{5}$.

The corresponding R-code to lead this test is given below.

```
observed_damaged_apples <- c(93.2,67.5,45.3,40.0,14.7)
expect_prob = c(1/5,1/5,1/5,1/5,1/5)

test <- chisq.test(observed_damaged_apples, p = expect_prob)
```

and the result is

```
    Chi-squared test for given probabilities

data:  observed_damaged_apples
X-squared = 67.468, df = 4, p-value = 7.768e-14
```

As you can see the p-value is near to $0$ and if you are testing with a significance level of $5\%$, the null hypothesis is rejected.

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate your taking the time to answer my enquiry.